# Embedding LibGDX into Swing, nothing is drawn

Tags: java, swing, libgdx, game-engine

I am trying to embed a LibGDX game into a JFrame through LWJGLCanvas. I am trying to do it as many people did. Using SwingUtils.invoke later. The game seems to run perfectly fine in the background(game logs are output into the terminal), but nothing is being drawn onto my JFrame or maybe the canvas. Not sure. What I am trying to achieve is to have the game run on the left side of the jframe and on the right side i'll have a penel for all features i need for my level editor.  panel on the right runs just fine. but the game on the left does not.

How can I fix this issue?

Here's the code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.boomer.alphaassault.AlphaAssault;
import core.enjineutils.EditPanel;
import core.enjineutils.LevelPanel;
import core.enjineutils.NewLevelPanel;


import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;



public class MapEditorLauncher extends JFrame implements         ActionListener,WindowListener{
private static final String TITLE = "EnJine2D Level Editor";

private static final int APP_SIZE_WIDTH = 1224;
private static final int APP_SIZE_HEIGHT = 828;

private LevelPanel levelPanel;
private EditPanel editPanel;
private NewLevelPanel newLevelPanel;

JMenuItem newLevel;
JMenuItem loadLevel;
JMenuItem saveLevel;
JMenuItem exit;

JMenuItem undo;
JMenuItem redo;

JMenuItem showTileGrids;

private LwjglCanvas levelCanvas;





public static void main(String[] args) {
    MapEditorLauncher app = new MapEditorLauncher();
    app.setVisible(true);
}

public MapEditorLauncher() {
    super(TITLE);
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    addWindowListener(this);





    setLayout(null);
    setSize(APP_SIZE_WIDTH,APP_SIZE_HEIGHT);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    JMenu map  = new JMenu("Map");

    newLevel  = new JMenuItem("New Level");
    loadLevel = new JMenuItem("Load Level");
    saveLevel = new JMenuItem("Save Level");
    exit     = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    undo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
    redo = new JMenuItem("Redo");

    showTileGrids  = new JMenuItem("Show tile grids");

    newLevel.addActionListener(this);file.add(newLevel);
    loadLevel.addActionListener(this);file.add(loadLevel);
    saveLevel.addActionListener(this);file.add(saveLevel);
    exit.addActionListener(this);file.add(exit);


    undo.addActionListener(this);edit.add(undo);
    redo.addActionListener(this);edit.add(redo);

    showTileGrids.addActionListener(this);map.add(showTileGrids);

    menuBar.add(file);
    menuBar.add(edit);
    menuBar.add(map);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);


}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem selection = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
    if(selection.equals(newLevel)){
        popNewLevel();
        return;
    }
}

private void popNewLevel(){
    newLevelPanel = new NewLevelPanel();
    newLevelPanel.initialize();
    if(newLevelPanel.getLevel()!=null){
        initialize();
    }
}

private void initialize(){
    editPanel = new EditPanel();
    levelPanel = new LevelPanel(editPanel);
    levelPanel.setLevel(newLevelPanel.getLevel());

    AlphaAssault gameInstance = new AlphaAssault();
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration configuration = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    configuration.width = 824;
    configuration.height = 768;
    final LwjglCanvas lwjglCanvas = new LwjglCanvas(gameInstance,configuration);
    levelCanvas = lwjglCanvas;


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            add(lwjglCanvas.getCanvas());
        }
    });

    //add(levelPanel);
    add(editPanel);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    levelCanvas.stop();
}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {

}
```

}

Comment: In short, no, this will give you no end of issues.  Swing uses a lightweight painting process, while `java.awt.Canvas`, which (I believe) `LWJGLCanvas` is based on, uses a heavyweight painting process, the two don't like playing nicely together.  Even if you could get something to display, you'll always have odd painting issues which appear randomly

Comment: Also, `initialize` is already running within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, so there's no need for `invokeLater` in fact, you should only need to include `revalidate` and `repaint` to get the components to update, BUT, you've shot yourself in the foot by doing `setLayout(null);`, which means your components are unmanaged and will have a default size of `0x0`.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details and some ideas about solutions

Comment: @MadProgrammer the initialize method isn't overriding anything, its just something that's called after a menu selection to show everything inside the JFrame. Absolute positioning is also mentioned in the link you provided and it worked just fine so far. Besides the layout issue, is there a way of being able to achieve what I want to do? As I said , I use null layouts in all my components and they all work fine, the only thing that won't render is the game itself despite running fine in the background.

Comment: *"JFrame. Absolute positioning is also mentioned in the link you provided and it worked just fine so far"* - And now it's not, otherwise we wouldn't be having this conversation. *"the initialize method isn't overriding anything" - from what I can tell, the method is been called from the `actionPerformed` method, which is triggered by some user interaction (clicking a menu item), then it is executed within the context of the EDT, making the use of `invokeLater` unnecessary.

Comment: *"I use null layouts in all my components and they all work fine"* until you run on a system with a different resolution or DPI or base font size and the whole thing just ends up looking like garbage. That is, of course your choice, but you should expect random and unexplained problems

Comment: You're right about the heavy/light weight not working well together. I'll try to add lwjgl canvas directly into the container and go from there . Probably to a completely different way of doing things. But i'll try to keep null lay outs as much as possible. I just hate having to deal with layouts haha. Thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to upvote your comments but i cant accept them as an answer since they werent posted as answers. if you can post an answer i will accept it